# Where can I find the most updated version of Castle DynamicProxy for .NET 2.0?

Tags: .net-2.0, aop, castle-dynamicproxy

I'm stuck to a Visual Studio 2005 solution; is there still a way to do AOP in .NET 2.0 nowadays? I really can't find it on Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to download them straight from Sourceforge:

[Castle Project - Browse/DynamicProxy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/castleproject/files/DynamicProxy/)

Comment: Thanks... I really suck at browsing sourceforge :P

Answer (score 0):

You can also use LinFu. See here: http://code.google.com/p/linfu/